# Loadrunner Controller - License expiration date

Tags: testing, loadrunner

Soooo for some reasons, i had to change my system date to a future date (2018). Now, everytime i try to open the Controller (just with Controller, not VuGen or Analysis) i get the message bellow. I tried re-installing the Loadrunner, but it seems that it keeps taking the future year since i'm still getting that message.
My version is Loadrunner Community 12.5.
I would like to know a way to change back the date to the present or how to do a clean unsintall, whatever it takes to make the controller work again.

[Here is the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRVck.png)

Answer (score 0):

Wipe the OS or Call support (which requires a paid contract).  For obvious reasons the license manager is pretty tight because people have tried all sorts of things over the years to circumvent an expiring license.  You have likely been trapped by code which checks for such behavior and unfortunately to disclose how to address this would also likely disclose how to defeat aspects of the license manager for unscrupulous individuals

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
I've tried a clean uninstall but everytime i try to re-install the LR, it maintains the future date of the previous installation. Everything happened because i was trying to record an app that had the test data in 2018 so i had to change the date.
I guess i'll try to contact the support to see if they can give me a solution. It shouldn't be a problem, since the community license isn't supposed to expire.

Comment: You will need to wipe the OS.   I see no reason why you needed to change the date on the operating system.

Unless you have a paid support contract I don't see how you will get access to support